# Create a matrix view from raw data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am using Power BI to create a dashboard and want to take source data that looks like this (2 columns):

```
Game      PLATFORM
--------  --------
Game 1    Mobile
Game 2    PC
Game 2    Console
Game 3    Mobile
Game 3    PC
Game 4    Mobile
Game 4    Console
```

....

and create this kind of view using Power BI:

```
             Mobile          PC          Console
Game 1         x
Game 2                        x             x
Game 3         x              x
Game 4         x                            x
....
```

Is this possible and if so how can we do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a matrix visual and put the `Game` column on in the Rows section and the `PLATFORM` column in the columns section and the count of either of those two in the values section, you'll get a table like this:

[image: Matrix Visual]

If you need the `x` values instead, define a measure based on the count and put that in the values section.

```
Measure = IF(COUNT(Table1[Game]) > 0, "x", BLANK())
```